# curl ok, RestTemplate fails

Tags: spring, spring-rest

This works:

```
curl --verbose -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"parm1\":\"1\",  \"parm2\":\"1\"}" http://server:8080/service/meth
```

and returns:

```
{"success":true,"errorMessage":null}
```

This fails:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();        
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("parm1", "1");
    map.add("parm2", "1");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

    String response = (String) restTemplate.postForObject("http://server:8080/service/meth", 
                                                          request, 
                                                          String.class);
```

with 500 Internal Server Error

I'm using springframework-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE and java 1.8 and am at a loss as to what's wrong.  The server side log shows no errors other than 500

Has anyone been faced with a Spring RestTemplate call that mysteriously failed?  How did you approach diagnosing the problem?